# prefix the class name and only use the mthod

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

in laravel 5.4 i want to prefix the controller name so i only have to write the methods name and can change the controller name with only one step in the route file

that doesn't work

```
Route::prefix('log')->group(function () {
    Route::get('log', '@loginForm')->name('log');

    Route::post('login', '@login')->name('log');

    Route::get('logout', '@logout')->name('log');
});
```

with the error

```
NotFoundHttpException
```

Comment: Use a variable if you want to change the controller name with one step, but realistically I don't see you changing **just** the controller name very often.

Comment: Why would you want it this anyway? You'd have a log controller with a loginForm method, a login controller with a login method and a logout controller with a logout method. Surely it'd be better to have an AuthController with all the relevant methods?

Comment: I think you missed controller name add in your route

Comment: @BenLewisWatson that's the idea maybe i or my partner/s mischoice a proper name for a class and we need to change it so i wanted to make this less painful

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd you missed the whole thing, i want to avoid write the controller name over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it's not possible out of the box.

`Route::prefix()` is for sharing **route** (URI) prefix, not a controller class name, within the group. The only other shareable attributes, besides the route prefix, are

- controllers namespace
- middleware
- domain